# Log4J : Cannot create file using environment variable

Tags: java, log4j, rollingfileappender

I have the following property

```
# Set the name of the file
log4j.appender.FILE.File="${env:LOG_DIR}/log.out"
```

and i can see the environment variable as

```
System.out.println(System.getenv("LOG_DIR"));
```

gives me

```
../../myLogFolder
```

but when i run my program it creates a folder by the name `"` and creates a `log.out` file inside. Why cant log4j.properties get the value of the environment variable?

here are my maven dependencies

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
```

**EDIT: Changed everything to 2.X compliance**

updated java code

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;

public class ABC {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(ABC.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(System.getenv("LOG_DIR"));
        logger.debug(System.getenv("LOG_DIR"));

    }
}
```

now, on the console i see

```
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
../../myLogsFolder
```

and it still creates the folder with the name `"`

Comment: This syntax is documented only in log4j 2.X so make sure you are using the correct version.

Comment: oh ok, i have `1.2.17`, how should i modify?

Comment: Can you show your full configuration file? Also, be aware that Log4j 2 will look for files named log4j2.xml (or properties, json or yml) in the classpath. Note the 2 in the name. It will ignore log4j.xml and log4j.properties by default.

Answer (score 0):

Added as an answer:

You should remove log4j 1.2.17 and add log4j 2.X libraries:

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/download.html

Comment: i'm afraid that did not help

Comment: From the website (How to migrate log4j) https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html

Comment: Use log4j.appender.FILE.File="${sys:LOG_DIR}/log.out". Btw you can read some http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html

Comment: why sys? its an environment variable. and i changed everything to version 2.X but still i get the same results